# Error in installing package in python

Tags: windows, python-3.x, command-line, pip

[I have installed pip but when i try to install requests , i get the following error as in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJRch.png)

Answer (score 0):

Pip should be run from the command line. It looks like you're running it from the Python interpreter.

```
C:\Users\ishan.nitj>pip install requests
```

If you're unable to call pip from the command line, add the following to your PATH.

```
C:\Python32\scripts
```

Since pip is used to install modules, it is not a Python command and thus shouldn't be run from the interpreter.